# Using an unmanaged struct from an unmanaged DLL without copying in C#

Tags: c#, dll, pinvoke

I have a DLL written in unmanaged language that returns a pointer to a C structure. 
A C# program must fill in some details into the structure.
Next the same pointer (not a copy) must be given to another method from the same DLL
Now the C# program collects the data from the C structure.

The datatype:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, Pack = 1, Size = 18 * 2 + 24 * 256)]
public class Context {
    public UInt16 Magic;
    public UInt16 Method;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 2*16)]
    public UInt16[] Status;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8*256)]
    public Field[]  InputFields;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8*256)]
    public Field[]  OutputFields;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8*256)]
    public Field[]  MetaData;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential,CharSet=CharSet.Unicode,Pack=1,Size=256)]
public class Field {
    public UInt16 Kind;
    public UInt16 Status;
    public UInt16 Length;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 125)]
    public string Data;
}
```

Methods:

```
[DllImport("x.dll")]
//[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)]
public static extern IntPtr  CreateContext    ( UInt16 ContextKind );
[DllImport("x.dll")]
public static extern UInt16  DestroyContext   ( IntPtr Context );
[DllImport("x.dll")]
public static extern UInt16  Execute          ( [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Context Context );
```

How can I fill in / read out the memory that is mananged by the DLL (not C#) in my C# program?

I tried:

- Using

  ```
  [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)]
  ```

  instead of `IntPtr`. But memory needs to be managed by C# for that which it is not.
- Use `IntPtr` and `Marshal.PtrToStructure` but it tries to copy the memory to another location:

  ```
  IntPtr C = CreateContext(1);
  if (C == null) return;
  Context Ctx = (Context)Marshal.PtrToStructure(C, typeof( Context ) );
  Ctx.Method = 2;
  ```

(fails on the `PtrToStructure` call with an `ExecutionEngineException`).

Comment: tagging C was in error?

Comment: @Deduplicator It is a DLL with a C interface, hence the tag. I dubbed about it and added it.

Comment: You mean with a native interface. Nothing to do with C, which is hust one of many ways to create native code, like assembler, C++, pascal, delphi, ...

Comment: Try `Marshal.Write*` to write to the memory directly without using `PtrToStructure`. Or fix your declaration so that you can use `PtrToStructure` (I guess you'd have to remove `Size`, why is it there in the first place?) - then you'll need to remember `Marshal.Copy` from the structure to the IntPtr after you're done with it.

Comment: @GSerg: I used Marshal.Write* and it works without copying and is fast (but a bit less readable). Can you create an answer to the question? Adding the Size to the declaration was me trying to get it to work. It did not with or without the size.

Comment: SO users make a traditional mistake when they ask pinvoke questions.  They post the version of their code they tried *last*, after hacking it for a while, trying to make it work.  Compounding errors, it just is no longer recognizable what the C code declaration looked like.  You **must** document the native C declaration to get a usable answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try fixing your declarations - e.g. remove the `Size` parameter (but not `SizeConst`), and make sure the C code actually provides inline, byval arrays of values that have exactly the right number of entries in them (which is the requirement for `UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst`). E.g. this works for me:

```
// Init array fields (required; supposed to happen on the C side)
ctx.Status = new UInt16[2 * 16];
ctx.InputFields = new Field[8 * 256];
ctx.OutputFields = new Field[8 * 256];
ctx.MetaData = new Field[8 * 256];

// Test data to survive the roundtrip (also supposed to happen on the C side)
ctx.Method = 42;
ctx.InputFields[42] = new Field() { Data = "Hi." };
ctx.OutputFields[42] = new Field() { Data = "Also hi." };


IntPtr buf = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(1024 * 100);

Marshal.StructureToPtr(ctx, buf, false);

var ctx_new = new Context();
Marshal.PtrToStructure(buf, ctx_new);

Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(buf);


Console.WriteLine(ctx_new.Method);
Console.WriteLine(ctx_new.InputFields[42].Data);
Console.WriteLine(ctx_new.OutputFields[42].Data);
```

---

Failing that, try using the `Marshal.Write*` methods to write to the memory directly if `PtrToStructure` does not work for you. You can then create a wrapper class that would hold the `IntPtr` and provide properties that would trigger the `Marshal.Write` - e.g.

```
public UInt16 Status {
    get { return unchecked((ushort)Marshal.ReadInt16(m_Ptr, 2)); }
    set { Marshal.WriteInt16(m_Ptr, 2, unchecked((short)value)); }
}
```